# client has had their whole Active Directory DNS (only dns) wiped out? how?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, active-directory

had a soon to be client had their whole DNS tables wiped, both forward and reverse lookup and of course no backups. any thoughts on how this might of happened. this is more for curiosity. thanks.

Comment: this is prior to my take over so again looking for how something like this could happen, i figured if somehow dns was removed you can just re-add it from the add roles menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Were these AD integrated zones? If so and there's no system state backup and no other domain controllers you may be out of luck. If these zones were not AD integrated then you should be able to find the zone files in the %SystemRoot%\System32\dns folder. Simply recreate the zones using the same zone names and Windows should load the zones from the existing files.

Comment: Regardless of how they were deleted, recreate them as AD integrated zones, setup aging and scavenging, bounce the Netlogon service on the DCs, and run an "IPCONFIG /registerdns" on the servers and you'll be in reasonable shape.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, yes that is probably how i would of ended up doing it, BUT the client ended up getting someone to rebuild the WHOLE domain from scratch. again this is way before i have come on, which will be in the next 3 weeks. in my opinion they should of been AD integrated if the original team that did it three years ago did it as a dcpromo. anyways thanks for the advice.

Comment: If for nothing else, this is a good argument for why there should always be at leat 2 DC's in every AD domain and failing that, why there should always be good system state backups of the DC.

Comment: believe it or not they did have another server there onsite that was a dc with dns and i guess the dns removal was replicated? so their second dc was gone too. they had backups but no strategy to ever test the backups for disaster recovery so they were stuck with lto tapes that were not working when they needed it.